# Js - Append a value to element CSS

Tags: javascript, css

This seems so simply yet its not working (undefined).

I have set a var to `<ul>` which is a child of `<div>` element "feature_tabs_indicators".
The pBoxShadowProperty function gets the BoxShadow property supported by the current browser.

And the final statement merely sets the pBoxShadowProperty to 0, i.e. its overriding the CSS set Box-Shadow property.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here in the last statement?

Best,

```
var iActiveNo = 0;
var eTabInd = document.getElementById ("feature_tabs_indicators").children[0];
var pBoxShadowProperty = getSupportedCSSproperty(["boxShadow", "mozBoxShadow", "webkitBoxShadow"]);

function getSupportedCSSproperty (propertyArray)
{
    var root = document.documentElement;
    for (var i = 0; i < propertyArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (typeof root.style[propertyArray[i]] === "string")
        {
            return propertyArray[i];
        }
    }
}

iActiveNo = iActiveNo + 1;
eTabInd.children[iActiveNo - 1].style[pBoxShadowProperty] = "";
```

[Here is the jsfiddle, press the light green button 'rght' on top right.](http://jsfiddle.net/RtaK7/6/)

Comment: Could you possibly expand on what is not working exactly?

Comment: Have just pasted the jsfiddle code @ZenMaster

To clarify, the box shadow property is not being dynamically set. I have set box shadow with CSS. When the user presses the green button, the box shadow should be removed.

Comment: What is supposed to happen? In any case - you have errors in that fiddle - see console. The line: `var pBackgroundColorProperty = eStyle.backgroundColor //[pBoxShadowProperty];` doesn't end with a semicolon, and is then interpreted as a function due to (..) on the next line (I think).
If semicolon is added - everything seems to be working.

Comment: Excellent find. Thank you +ZenMaster. The semi-colon was the problem all along... I accidently placed it at the end of comment instead of before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out what your issue is. You use here:

```
iActiveNo = iActiveNo + 1;
```

something that has not been defined in your posted code. However you do have:

```
var iActive = 0;
```

which I think should have actually been:

```
var iActiveNo = 0;
```

otherwise your code has JS error in it (as it is posted, anyway).

Other than that (that is, if your intention was to take the 1st `<li>` element out of the `<ul>` element and remove its `box-shadow` CSS property) - your code is just fine.

**Edit**

Dude, what a mess.. :) Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSgGU/) I fixed up a bit. Below is the explanation.

There are several things going on in that JSFiddle that should be fixed before we get to the real problem.

You have errors in that fiddle - see console. The line:

```
var pBackgroundColorProperty = eStyle.backgroundColor //[pBoxShadowProperty];
```

doesn't end with a semicolon, and is then interpreted as a function due to (..) on the next line (I think) - which (for me at least) results in an error in JS console. If semicolon is added - error is gone.

Additionally... There is a line:

`console.log (eTabInd.children[iActiveNo-1].style.pBoxShadowProperty);`

which prints your `undefined` and is exactly what was discussed below and should be

```
console.log (eTabInd.children[iActiveNo-1].style[pBoxShadowProperty]);
```

which then prints the empty string.

Moreover, when printed, your `pBoxShadowProperty` variable contains `boxShadow` string. Which is, of course, not a valid CSS property I am familiar with. So this:

```
eTabInd.children[iActiveNo - 1].style[pBoxShadowProperty] = "";
```

won't do a thing.

Now to the meat of the issue here...

```
eTabInd.children[iActiveNo-1].style
```

doesn't have 'box-shadow' property to begin with, because you haven't put it in `style` attribute of `<li>` element. It is put on the `<li>` element through the virtues of this CSS selectors sequence: `#feature_tabs_indicators ul #ind_bt`.

Now, since you wanted the `style` attribute - you won't get the computed style the above CSS selectors sequence applies. Thus - you won't be able to remove it.

What you could have done is create another class, that doesn't have a `box-shadow` property and replace your original `c_ind` with it.

Comment: thanks @ZenMaster. That was a typo, it is correctly defined in the code.

I'll upload it to jsfiddle & post the code.

Comment: Correct answer is in the mini-comment to the question by ZenMaster.

Comment: @SalmanKhan I am afraid it's not all, my friend. See update above.

Comment: Dude, you rock! A million & one thanks for the clarification O' master of Zen. However, I think you have a few things wrong in the above.

boxShadow is the js version of Box-shadow property & it does work. Yes, it doesn't work, for reason unknown to me as yet, when you insert value = "", replacing the "" with "0 0 0 transparent" does work.

I'm not sure I follow the explanation in the third para from the bottom but here is what is going on in my code. The list item CSS is in external file which gets superseeded by the inline CSS written by Js (in this case boxShadow).

Comment: The function getSupportedCSSproperty gets which syntax is relevant to the user's browser.The resultant is assigned to variable pBoxShadowProperty, which itself is linked to style attribute of the element. One mistake that I just caught was the syntax for boxShadow. I extract the backgroundColor property & assign it to pBackgroundColorProperty, which would be in the format 'rgb()', however, as the boxShadow property requires 'x x x rgb()', I need to insert the Xs which I hadn't done. Now that I have, its working beautifully with a huge thanks to you. Cheers again for the awesome help!

Comment: @ZenMaster... I forgot to add your name so you can get notified. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you have not set value correctly as it should be like

```
eTabInd.children[iActiveNo - 1].style.pBoxShadowProperty = "";
```

Dose that help or dose still return 0?

Comment: `pBoxShadowProperty` is a variable and as such should be accessed through [] - just as the OP has done. Your way won't work.

Comment: @ZenMaster true it will just return the css property

Comment: ZenMaster is right, it wont because style is not an object whose property (pBoxShadowProperty) is being set.

Comment: @david Nope. What would happen is you adding a new, totally CSS unrelated property `pBoxShadowProperty` to `eTabInd.children[iActiveNo - 1].style` object and assigning a string (that just happens to contain some CSS values) to it.

Comment: right i see thanks for the update guys, i shouldnt of tryed to answer the question without exactly knowing what was not working